# @Nuxt/Apollo How can i remove "__typeName" from gql query

Tags: vue.js, apollo, nuxt.js

I am working on nuxt/apollo package but there is no information about addTypeName property. Where should be set this property ? 
Note: All installations working about @nuxt/apollo. (imported as module etc.)

**Version info :**

```
"@nuxtjs/apollo": "^4.0.0-rc8",
```

> My apollo config in nuxt.config.js :

```
    apollo: {
    includeNodeModules: false,
    authenticationType: 'Basic',
    defaultOptions: {
      $query: {
        loadingKey: 'loading',
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
      }
    },
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: 'DEFAULT_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT',
        tokenName: 'apollo-token' // optional
      },
      financial: {
        httpEndpoint: 'NEWS_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT',
        tokenName: 'apollo-token',
        addTypename: false --> **Is not working**
      }
    }
  }
```

> My Index.vue page is :

```
apollo: {
data: {
  query: gql`
    {
      newsJson(take: 1) {
        key
        *GENERATES __typeName when sending request to Graphql*
      }
    }
  `,
  client: 'financial'
}
}
```

> My graphql query (via graphiql on web) :

```
{
  newsJson(take:1){
    key
    approve
  }
}
```

> And **Response** is :

```
{
  "data": {
    "newsJson": [
      {
        "key": 2071554,
        "approve": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When i sent request __typeName crashes me on graphql web side. How can i prevent adding **__typeName** property to request ?

Best Regards,

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "__typeName crashes me on graphql web side". The property added by Apollo is **__typename**, not **__typeName**. This is [a standard meta field added by GraphQL](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Type-Name-Introspection). If you're attempting to request **__typeName** (not **__typename**) in GraphiQL, then you will get an error because no such field exists.

Comment: There's no reason that the client appending the **__typename** field would cause any issues with your query. Omitting the field, on the other hand, can cause issues with your client.

Comment: @DanielRearden My gql function (graphql-tag) generates query that including _typeName (built-in) field and send to graphql endpoint. (I wasn't add this field manually.) This state causing issue on graphql endpoint.  Example gql output to will send endpoint --> {newsJson(take:1){ key *_typeName* }}

Comment: [graphql-tag](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag) only transforms a string into a GraphQL DocumentNode object. It does not add any fields to your request. If the request being sent to the server is ending up with `__typeName` instead of `__typename`, there's something else going on. Maybe you could provide a repo link to the full code or provide a sandbox with the bug reproduced.

Comment: I m working on sandbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `InMemoryCache` takes an optional `addTypename` parameter that can be set to `false` to prevent this behavior. So you can do something like:

```
clientConfigs: {
  default: {
     ...
     inMemoryCacheOptions: {
       addTypename: false,
     },
  },
}
```

However, it's **highly inadvisable** to do this. The `__typename` field, along with the `id`/`_id` field, is used to generate the key for an individual node in the cache. See [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.5/advanced/caching/#normalization) for additional details. Removing the `__typename` will likely cause errors and unexpected behavior in your app and should not be done.

Comment: I updated my config but still same... i am going to edit my post.